# DMV Index proposals still reported as missing

Tags: sql-server, index, index-tuning, dmv

We have recently converted a big client running our patient/journal application from ORACLE to MSSQL, and after the conversion we have had quite a few performance issues.

After running the DMV query:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
PRINT '-- MissingIndexes'
DECLARE @ProductVersion NVARCHAR(128)
SET @ProductVersion = CAST(SERVERPROPERTY ('ProductVersion') AS NVARCHAR(128))

IF CAST(LEFT(@ProductVersion, CHARINDEX('.',@ProductVersion)-1) AS INT) > 8
BEGIN
SELECT
  IndexImpact = user_seeks * avg_total_user_cost * (avg_user_impact * 0.5),
  LastUserSeek = groupstats.last_user_seek,
  FullObjectName = details.[statement],
  TableName = REPLACE(REPLACE(REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(details.[statement]), 
    CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(details.[statement]))-1)),'[',''), ']',''),
  EqualityColumns = details.equality_columns,
  InequalityColumns = details.inequality_columns,
  IncludedColumns = details.included_columns,
  Compiles = groupstats.unique_compiles,
  Seeks = groupstats.user_seeks,
  UserCost = groupstats.avg_total_user_cost,
  UserImpact = groupstats.avg_user_impact, 
  DatabaseName = DB_NAME(details.database_id)
FROM
  sys.dm_db_missing_index_group_stats AS groupstats
  INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_missing_index_groups AS groups
    ON groupstats.group_handle = groups.index_group_handle
  INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_missing_index_details AS details
    ON groups.index_handle = details.index_handle
ORDER BY
  IndexImpact DESC ;
END
```

We got a massive list of reported "missing indexes", with quite a bit of "IndexImpact".

After we retrieved the list of indexes, we narrowed the list down to a handful which we reckoned would suffice to fix the most critical issues and added those.

One of the indexes we added was the following:

```
 IndexImpact  TABLE    EQ-Columns  INEQ-COLUMNS  INCLUDED
 69287773     JOURNAL  NULL        EmpId         All columns in the table(*)
```

After the indexes was added we tried the DMV query again, but this index and a few others like it where still reported as missing. We blamed this on not having reset the execution plans and cleared the cache buffers, so we ran:

```
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
```

But even after running those queries the indexes where still reported as missing.

We have not identified the code that executes this exact query, but running the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM JOURNAL WHERE EmpId = 3
```

Results in the following execution plan:

[image: execution plan]

Are we missing something? Or is it just reported as missing because the server has not been restarted since the index was added?

Comment: Did the numbers for the seeks/scan columns change from before you created the indexes? Also, did you look into the missing index details? You should be able to right-click on the execution plan to get the scripts to create the missing indexes which you'll see if it's the same index that you created manually. Also, note the limitations of missing indexes (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345485.aspx). Database tuning advisor will provide better results.